# Отключение листания в UIScrollView при перемещении элемент

Tags: ios, objective-c, прокрутка

Имеется большая листалка UIScrollView (произвольное количество страниц). На некоторых страницах есть игры. Например, перемещение элемента с одного места на другое. Или нарисовать что-то. При прикосновении элемента или касании в области рисования я отключаю работу uiscrollview следующим образом:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [self setMainScrollDisable];
}
```

Где метод через делегата обращается к scrollview:

```
- (void)setMainScrollDisable {
    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(setScrollDisable:)]) {
        [self.delegate setScrollDisable:YES];
    }
}
```

И всё бы ничего, но это помогает только когда картинку подержишь, а вот если тащишь в любую сторону, то всё равно срабатывает scrollview.

Что можно сделать с этим?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У скролл вью есть проперти `delayContentTouches`, если ее выключить `= NO`, то скролл должен сразу передавать touch event следующему респондеру. Пока она включена (дефолт), он будет ждать какое то время чтобы убедиться что пользователь хотел именно нажать, а не скролиить. И если за это время touch сдвинется, то произойдет скролл - именно то, что у вас и происходит.

```
self.scrollView.delayContentTouches = NO;
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Только надо наоборот, выставлять в NO, тогда работает как нужно.

Comment: ой блин, точно. исправил ответ

Answer (score 0):

Можно отлавливать момент нажатия через тот метод, который Вы указали, в нем:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self];

    if ([[touch.view class] isSubclassOfClass:[UIView class]]) {
        if (CGRectContainsPoint(self.myView.frame, touchLocation)) {
            self.scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;
        } else {
           self.scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
         }
    }
```